# Global variable 'not defined' when decleared in another function

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

I'm trying to run a package developed by others and it is giving me `NameError: name 'hg38' is not defined` error when I run. I try to summarize the issue here:

There is a python file with two functions. The first one has a global variable as

```
#global_var_test.py

def print_sth(a='ath'):
    global hg38
    hg38 = 555
    <do something here>
    

def process_del(gen):
    print(gen)
```

I call this file from another script as

```
import global_var_test

global_var_test.print_sth()
global_var_test.process_del(hg38)
```

which returns the error

`NameError: name 'hg38' is not defined`

What I'm trying summarize here is actually from this repository: https://github.com/jzhoulab/orca/tree/main

running the line (given in README) `outputs = process_dup('chr17', 70845859, 71884859, hg38, file='./chr17_70845859_71884859_RevSex_dup_maximum_Sox9', show_genes=True)` returns the same error.
Variable is defined in this function: https://github.com/jzhoulab/orca/blob/87beec0e52f9366043fda0d18a639d54c7a3bf04/orca_predict.py#LL37C25-L37C25
It is called here: https://github.com/jzhoulab/orca/blob/87beec0e52f9366043fda0d18a639d54c7a3bf04/orca_predict.py#L1163

Any ideas? I'd appreciate it if you can show me where I do wrong.

Comment: the function defining the variable marked as "global" has to be actually executed before the variable exists in the module escope .

Comment: can you be more clear about it? I tried executing it different places but couldn't succeed.

Comment: The variable `hg38` will also be defined in the module it is. What we call "global variables" in Python are actually "module"variable. You have, after calling the `print_sth` function, refer to it as `global_var_test.hg38`

Comment: Thank you @jsbueno. It makes sense and works now. I will put this as an answer unless you want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jsbueno commented, the second script should actually be

```
import global_var_test

global_var_test.print_sth()
global_var_test.process_del(global_var_test.hg38)
```